# Google Web Fonts don't work in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, fonts, google-webfonts

I'm using this to link to some Google Fonts:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=IM+Fell+English+SC|Snippet|Sarina|Crushed|Caesar+Dressing|Montez|Bad+Script|Sofia|Fontdiner+Swanky|Just+Me+Again+Down+Here|Voltaire|Geo|Coming+Soon|Wellfleet|Passion+One|Rock+Salt|Homemade+Apple|Meddon|Rosario' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

I'm using this code, which works in some browsers:

```
<span style="font-size: 110px;font-family:montez;"><b>Abcdefg</b></span>
```

Why doesn't the font doesn't appear in IE8? http://jsfiddle.net/3NbE5/

Comment: Why the 2 downvotes...?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694060/how-to-make-google-fonts-work-in-ie

Comment: @j08691 N.B. As of Oct 2010 the issue is reported as fixed and closed on the Google Code bug report.

Comment: It's not fair to downvote a person for having problems with IE. IE often fails at everything.

Comment: @TIMEX, did you get this work in actual `IE8` browser (not `IE8` mode inside `IE9`)? I asked because I copied the exact the code (also tried my own), but no Google web font is rendered in `IE8`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems that IE doesn't support multiple fonts in the href:
http://jsfiddle.net/3NbE5/3/

**You had this href:**

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=IM+Fell+English+SC|Snippet|Sarina|Crushed|Caesar+Dressing|Montez|Bad+Script|Sofia|Fontdiner+Swanky|Just+Me+Again+Down+Here|Voltaire|Geo|Coming+Soon|Wellfleet|Passion+One|Rock+Salt|Homemade+Apple|Meddon|Rosario' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

**After removing the other fonts it worked:**

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=IM+Fell+English+SC|Montez' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Comment: You still have two fonts there, so maybe it was something else in the query string, but I can confirm that this works now in IE9, IE8 mode.

Comment: Probably one of the fonts wasn't compatible with IE and caused all fonts to fail, or maybe the excessive quantity of loaded fonts were too much process for IE.

Comment: @TIMEX If my answer helps you, can you please mark it as correct? :)
Thanks! However, loading multiple fonts just slows down the loading of the page, so a good practice is to use no more than 2 for proyect...

Answer (score 1):

Just in case the solution above don't cut it for you.

I got multiple fonts working on ie8 without any problems. My actual problem was using **ie11 in compatibility mode for ie8**, where google web fonts don't seem to work in any possible way.

I guess the lesson is, use a **vm with the actual ie8**. You can grab one [here](https://github.com/xdissent/ievms) or [here](https://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools).