# Correctly Include font as link to work in IE8

Tags: html, css, fonts, internet-explorer-8, google-font-api

I add font to project by including it into my Master.Page as link :

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300italic,400italic,700italic,400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />

.font_roboto-condensedr { font-family: Roboto Condensed, sans-serif !important; }
```

and Add this class to `<body>`

But this doesn't work in IE8.

I saw this post with same problem **[Google Web Fonts don't work in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050747/google-web-fonts-dont-work-in-ie8)** but make font-link more simplier `<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />` also doesn't help.

So i don't know what to do.

Comment: I'd just ditch IE8 support lol.. it's really old

Comment: @MightyPork, i know :D but i have such requirment :(