# Custom Google Font in Internet Explorer 8+

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fonts

I want use a custom font in my website, called 'Source Sans Pro', from Google Fonts. It works in other browsers, like Chrome, Opera, Mozilla and Safari... but not in IE. I tried some ways to fix it, but without success. A strange situation, because, I solved it in other website some months ago, but I don't remember how. Can someone help me, please?

PS: Sorry for the mistakes, english is not my native language.

### --

So, I found the solution. Custom fonts (IE in this case) only work in online websites, not in localhost. Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694060/how-to-make-google-fonts-work-in-ie The answerer suggests that some google fonts, even after an apparent fix still don't work in IE. Use his alternatives instead.

Comment: Have you tried all three methods of adding the font?

Standard    @import   Javascript

Comment: Thanks adaam, but no results. @Ma9ic, what three methods?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried all three methods?

**Standard:**

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

**@import:**

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro);
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  WebFontConfig = {
    google: { families: [ 'Source+Sans+Pro::latin' ] }
  };
  (function() {
    var wf = document.createElement('script');
    wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
      '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
    wf.type = 'text/javascript';
    wf.async = 'true';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
  })(); </script>
```

http://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Source+Sans+Pro

Comment: Works in every browser, but not in IE 8/9 =|

Comment: You could try 

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/source-sans-pro

and click on there Webfont Kit.