# How to write condition in html for IE8 font

Tags: html, css

I am using Google font, 'Open Sans' for my website.
When I check the IE8, this font doesn't work.
To work in IE8, I have to add 'Open Sans' name to every h1,h2,,,,p in css.
Can I add condition for IE8 in html ?
If this is possible, how can I write?

### Thanks.

```
       <!--[if lt IE 8 ]>
      <link href="css/ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">          
    <![endif]-->
```

I add this in ,but didn't work.
Where should I put this comment? above my own css or below my own css?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Google Fonts work in IE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694060/how-to-make-google-fonts-work-in-ie)

Comment: Does the font not work if you apply it to the `body` tag? Are you asking for a workaround for having to specify the `font-family` for every tag or a way to only specify it for every tag in IE8?

Comment: If microsoft does not support ie8 you shouldn't either, just my opinion though...

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the browser you want a custom font and if it's not available, a default one with CSS.

Put this inside your head tag:

```
<style>
 body{
    font:  'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
</style>
```