# Html Google Fonts font doesn't work in Hebrew using Internet Explorer (works with Chrome & Firefox)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, utf-8, google-fonts

I have this Html code in the head (for the Google Font and for the utf-8 encoding for Hebrew):

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Suez+One" rel="stylesheet">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

I have this code in the style tag:

```
<style>
    body
    {
        background-color:#ff8000;
        font-family: 'Suez One', serif;
    }
</style>
```

When I write in English/ numbers the font works properly in all browsers, but when I write in Hebrew the font doesn't work in Internet Explorer (works only with Google Chrome and Firefox). 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: probably web fonts are disabled on IE settings. Have you tried it in Edge?

Comment: @Prajwal I would agree, but when I write in English/ numbers the font works (so the web fonts aren't disabled...)

Comment: check here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694060/how-to-make-google-fonts-work-in-ie

Comment: Are you getting any errors in console? Usually if there's an issue with font file, it will show up there.

Comment: @Prajwal Not any important/ relevant errors...